# Dynamically adding attributes to <head> tag ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

How would I go about finding  on my ASPX page (from codebehind) and then adding the attribute "runat=server" to it?
I have tried using  `Page.header.attributes.add(...)` and`(HtmlHead) Page.FindControl("head");` The second one obviously won't work as the Head tag doesnt have an ID.

I can't work out how to change this property and I can't change or add any additional code to the ASPX page - like ID's etc.

Comment: The element will not be available in the Controls collection unless it has the runat="server" attribute set in the template or is enclosed in an element with that attribute, so I am not aware of an easy way you can add it within the framework.

Comment: You can't add `runat="server"` from code-behind, because you can't access it programmatically unless it has `runat="server"` in the first place.  Kind of a catch 22.

Comment: there is a sample here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600772/can-we-avoid-few-of-the-css-files-which-are-there-in-master-page-to-load-in-the

Comment: I thought that might be the case... Hmm. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

The `runat="server"` attribute allows the code behind to "see" the element it decorates. If that attribute is not present in the page markup, the element will not be accessible from code behind and you will not be able to manipulate it.

The only way to achieve what you want is to add `runat="server"` (and possibly an `ID` attribute) to the element in the page markup. Only then will you be able to add other attributes, event handlers, etc. from the code behind.

Comment: Well, you can get at it without the ID, the ID just makes it easier, but the runat server is still needed...

Comment: @Servy, you're right in theory, but without an `ID` attribute there will be no member variable representing the element, and `FindControl()` will not be useable either. The only solution in that case is to identify the element from its position in the control collection, or by some other non-unique attribute, which is less robust.

Comment: I thought that this might be the case, I just wanted to avoid editing every single page in the application due to a mass check-in. I'll mark this as an answer when the time is up :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That's correct, but it still doesn't change the fact that it will exist in the Controls collection, so you can access it, it's just harder to access it directly.

Comment: @Servy, true, and on second thought `Page.Header` is a special case that requires neither a member variable nor `FindControl()`, so an `ID` attribute is definitely not necessary here. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The runat directive is a compile-time directive.

You can't add the attribute to existing elements at runtime.